# Can bananas really be ripened through oven baking?

Tags: baking, fruit, chemistry, ripe

I am following a diet for IBS called the Specific Carbohydrate Diet (SCD). 
Only bananas that are ripe, i.e. well spotted, can be consumed. Green and non-spotty can not be due to a difference in sugars.

I've seen a few posts on facebook saying that bananas can be ripened simply through baking them in the oven.

Does this really lead to the same change and resulting sugars as a ripe banana?

Comment: I doubt it, but cooking bananas certainly influences the chemistry a bit. I really don't like the taste of not quite ripe bananas raw, but don't at all mind them fried.

Comment: Baking won't, but you may want to try leaving the bananas in an opaque paper bag, making sure the stems are covered. This traps the gases which lead to ripening that the banana produces, making the bananas ripen considerably faster.

Answer (score 1):

No. Ripening is a specific chemical process. Baking the bananas has a similar effect in sweetening the fruit, but it is not the same as ripening, which is a process which occurs after exposure to ethylene gas (in a supermarket banana at least). Given that your diet seems very **specific** about the carbohydrates, I wouldn't diverge from its recommendations.